# WebDriver -- Selenium I can not select the dropdown option

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I can not understand what the problem is, tried different ways of choosing, I give examples below...
1. You must select or click a selection.
2. Select or click the desired language.
But WebDriver does not see, does not find these elements, but in DOM they are.
You need to go to LinkedIn profile, settings, language selection.

```
//Before select dropdown.
WebElement language = driver.findElement(By.id("setting-select-language"));
language.click();
//Select dropdown.
Select make = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("selectLanguage")));
make.selectByValue("en_US");
//Or 
Actions act = new Actions(driver);  
//XPath of dropdown.       
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name("selectLanguage"))).click().perform();
//XPath of option in the dropdown.
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='setting-select-language-content']/form/div/select/option[16]"))).click().perform();
```

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: Are you trying your code on this page -- https://www.linkedin.com/psettings/select-language?

Comment: yes,on this page

Answer (score 0):

[focus = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1imh.png)  [focus = false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BelMm.png)

When you click on select it changes focus = true

Comment: is this answer??

Answer (score 0):

I believe you locator for the select is incorrect, try something like the below code:

```
WebElement language = driver.findElement(By.id("setting-select-language"));
language.click();
Select make = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("//*[@id='setting-select-language-content']/form/div/select")));
make.selectByValue("en_US");
```